# Javascript not updating element in page

Tags: javascript

So I have this small code for a project:

```
var Symbols =  ["", "", "", "", "", ""];
var list = []; 
var Dic = [
    [GNER(), GNER()],
    [GNER(), GNER()],
    [GNER(), GNER()],
    [GNER(), GNER()],
    [GNER(), GNER()],
    [GNER(), GNER()]
];

function GNER()
{
    "use strict";
    var i;
    do
    {
        i = getRandomInt(0, 12);
    }
    while(list.includes(i));
    list.push(i); 
    return i;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function Init()
{
    "use strict";
    document.getElementById("TimeFooter").innerHTML = Date().toString();
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("B" + Dic[i][0]).value = Symbols[i];
        document.getElementById("B" + Dic[i][1]).value = Symbols[i];
    }
}

function Play(i) {
    "use strict";
    //TODO
    return 0;
}


window.onload = Init;
```

The Code works, just not always, it's supposed to change the values of buttons with the symbols scattered randomly, the problem is it works sometimes and some other times it does not change the button value, resulting in the following:

[Non-Working Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGWGB.png)

[Working Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLqRR.png)

I checked the 'index' values for each symbol every time and they're always correct, or at least logical both when it works and not

Comment: add the relevant HTML

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: it's the end of a `do`-`while` loop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while

Comment: @LukeWoodward. Wow, what's unusual, it looked as wrong positioned `;` to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 12 fields and this

```
i = getRandomInt(0, 12);
```

will return number 0..12 so up to 13 numbers.

Either `document.getElementById("B0")` or `document.getElementById("B12")` doesn't exists.

You should exactly see that in console (`setting innerHTML on null` error). Next time you should provide HTML and console errors or try to debug it by yourself as this is very trivial bug.